# Excel 2013: Count unique values or IDs in column B with a condition which needs to be filtered in column A

Tags: excel

I am a noob in excel, hence pardon me for any mistakes made.
This question must have been answered before but I couldn't find the right string to make it work for me.

There are around 500 rows and 20 columns (Yes, it is a report)

Column A has a few values (eg: Problem, Change, Request, etc.)
Column B has ticket numbers assigned to each entry. (No, I don't work for a call center, these are Datacenter Operations tickets)

Column B has several duplicate ticket numbers, as many people worked on same ticket OR the ticket was reopened for some reason.

I wish to take a count of unique ticket numbers from Column B when the condition in Column A is Change only.

So if there are 500 ticket number 250 are duplicate for sure, and only 25% of the rest will be Change tickets.

I am not supposed to use a Pivot or filter hence asking this question.
Need a formula to retrieve the count with the condition.
I may put the formula in Sheet2 or at the extreme right column, plz don't worry about it, I will take care of those things.

Many thanks in advance.

Adding to the question,
Let me help you with some data.

Change  CRQ1110001
Problem INC1110001
Change  CRQ1110001
Problem INC1110001
Change  CRQ1110003
Problem INC1110003
Change  CRQ1110004
Problem INC1110004
Change  CRQ1110004
Change  CRQ1110004
Problem INC1110005

Now I wish to only consider Change here without considering duplicate values.
Maybe this helps.

Thanks again.

Comment: You can have definitely some formula method to solve this but in my opinion best method will be to use a pivot...array formula usually takes a long time to process, pivot will be instant for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this website [count unique values](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-HP010070481.aspx) and with a small change this formula should work, expand the ranges to cover your entire range.

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A10="change",IF(LEN(B2:B10)>0,MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0),""),""), IF(A2:A10="change",IF(LEN(B2:B10)>0,MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0),""),""))>0,1))`

Entered with ctrl+shift+enter as it's an array formula.

Note that if you do this over the entire column `A:A` it will take quite a bit of time to compute as it has to go through a lot of calculations in the array formula.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't return desired output somehow.

Comment: That formula works for me - did you adjust the ranges? What result did you get, what did you expect? Note: there's a slightly simplified version of that formula in the link pnuts posted above

Comment: My bad, as I am still a noob. I should have understood the concept of CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, which I didn't. The formula was correct at the first time... Many thanks to you from the bottom of my heart. I was merely hitting ENTER which was resulting in 1 or #VALUE.

Answer (score 1):

If your "ticket numbers" in column B are actual numbers then you can use this formula

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A500="Change",B2:B500),B2:B500),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If not numeric you need to use a version as per gtwebb's suggestion

Comment: Did you use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER? If done correctly you'll get curly braces like { and } around the formula

Comment: OK, I notice you edited the question - your "ticket numbers" are alphanumeric, not actual numbers - use gtwebb's suggestion

Comment: Yes, tried the string shared by gtwebb and it worked like a charm. Many thanks to you too, for emphasizing on CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, else I wouldn't have done it. Cheers & Beers for you.